# Сокращение использования памяти

Tags: java, память, outofmemoryerror

Как можно в коде ниже сократить использование памяти? Ибо через некоторое время после запуска выдает OutOfMemoryError.

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 100000; i < 999999; i++) {

        for (int j = 100000000; j < 999999999; j++) {
            result.add("/c" + i + "/v" + j + "/");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Заносить в БД и очищать ArrayList

Comment: @Serodv, разве это не приведет к большИм затратам? Или Вы имеете в виду не создавать ArrayList вообще?

Comment: А что вы вообще хотели этим кодом сделать? По грубым подсчётам `result` должен занять 30174818 гигабайт памяти

Comment: @andreymal, ого. Похоже, придется сократить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

предлагаю использовать деревья в этом задании. исходя из моих расчет,они самые быстрые и требуют наименьшей памати, даже в таких кол-вах,как вам надо. вот код,где считается время каждой из коллекций,я не знаю используете ли вы только добавление, написал и для удаления и для поиска :

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collection;
 import java.util.HashSet;
 import java.util.LinkedList;
 import java.util.TreeSet;



public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<Integer> linked = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    HashSet<Integer> hash = new HashSet<Integer>();
    TreeSet<Integer> tree = new TreeSet<Integer>();


        System.out.println(" Время добавления в ArrayList<> " + add(array) );
        System.out.println(" Время добавления в LinkedList<> " + add(linked) );
        System.out.println(" Время добавления в HashSet<> " + add(hash) );
        System.out.println(" Время добавления в TreeSet<> " + add(tree) );
        System.out.println(" Время удаления в ArrayList<> " + remove(array) );
        System.out.println(" Время удаления в LinkedList<> " + remove(linked) );
        System.out.println(" Время удаления в HashSet<> " + remove(hash) );
        System.out.println(" Время удаления в TreeSet<> " + remove(tree) );
        System.out.println(" Время поиска в ArrayList<> " + contains(array) );
        System.out.println(" Время поиска в LinkedList<> " + contains(linked) );
        System.out.println(" Время поиска в HashSet<> " + contains(hash) );
        System.out.println(" Время поиска в TreeSet<> " + contains(tree) );


    }

    public static long add(Collection<Integer> collection){
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
            collection.add(i);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
        return end;
    }
        public static long remove(Collection<Integer>collection){
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
                collection.remove(i);
            }
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
            return end;
        }
        public static long contains(Collection<Integer>collection){
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(int i =0;i<10000;i++){
                collection.contains(i);
            }
            long end=System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
            return end;

        }

}
```

ВЫВОД :

```
    Время добавления в ArrayList<> 28
    Время добавления в LinkedList<> 1611
    Время добавления в HashSet<> 797
    Время добавления в TreeSet<> 227
    Время удаления в ArrayList<> 4611
    Время удаления в LinkedList<> 2
    Время удаления в HashSet<> 3
    Время удаления в TreeSet<> 10
    Время поиска в ArrayList<> 20707
    Время поиска в LinkedList<> 109081
    Время поиска в HashSet<> 2
    Время поиска в TreeSet<> 4
```

из этого следует выбрать или HashSet<> или TreeSet<> для вашего задания.